# Add an equation at the bottom of a two-column article

Tags: equations, positioning, two-column, article

How can I place a two-column equation (a large equation that does not fit in one column) at the bottom of a page?

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/latexusersgroup/browse_thread/thread/afb2c7af73d6564e describes an approach using `multicols`.

Comment: If you are trying to do that in an IEEE Journal paper (notoriously 2-column), then you may want to read the style guide, where they give another approach, using `\begin{figure*}` (which has some limitations, though... they recommend to break the equation across multiple lines instead). The details can be found in the [IEEE Author Digital Tool Box](http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/authors_journals.html), section X-D1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `multicol` package. Either you end a multicol environment before the equation and restart it after, or you define an environment like this:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\OneColEqu}[1]{%
\end{multicols}%
\begin{equation}%
#1
\end{equation}%
\begin{multicols}{2}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{x=0}^{x=5}(x^2+2x-3) dx = \left[ \frac{1}{3}x^3+x^2-3x+C \right]^{x=5}_{x=0} = \frac{125}{3}+25-15+C-C= \frac{155}{3}
\end{equation} 
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2]
\OneColEqu{\int\limits_{x=0}^{x=5}(x^2+2x-3) dx = \left[ \frac{1}{3}x^3+x^2-3x+C \right]^{x=5}_{x=0} = \frac{125}{3}+25-15+C-C= \frac{155}{3}}
\lipsum[3]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Both approches yield the same, but the own command probably is more convineant:

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** Putting the equation always on the bottom can be achieved by defining a custom float with the `float` package:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}

\floatstyle{plain}
\newfloat{twocolequfloat}{b}{zzz}
\floatname{twocolequfloat}{Equation}

\newcommand{\OneColEqu}[1]{%
\end{multicols}%
\begin{twocolequfloat}%
\ensuremath{\hfill #1 \hfill}%
\end{twocolequfloat}%
\begin{multicols}{2}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-3]
\OneColEqu{\int\limits_{x=0}^{x=5}(x^2+2x-3) dx = \left[ \frac{1}{3}x^3+x^2-3x+C \right]^{x=5}_{x=0} = \frac{125}{3}+25-15+C-C= \frac{155}{3}}
\lipsum[3-7]
\OneColEqu{\int\limits_{x=0}^{x=5}(x^2+2x-3) dx = \left[ \frac{1}{3}x^3+x^2-3x+C \right]^{x=5}_{x=0} = \frac{125}{3}+25-15+C-C= \frac{155}{3}}
\lipsum[8-14]
\OneColEqu{\int\limits_{x=0}^{x=5}(x^2+2x-3) dx = \left[ \frac{1}{3}x^3+x^2-3x+C \right]^{x=5}_{x=0} = \frac{125}{3}+25-15+C-C= \frac{155}{3}}
\lipsum[15]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

- `\floatstyle{plain}` same stlye as LaTex (no rules around the float)
- `\newfloat{twocolequfloat}{b}{zzz}` new float *twocolequfloat*, which is always aligned *bottom*, for posiible use in `listof...` or something the file .zzz will be written
- `\floatname{twocolequfloat}{Equation}` name displaed e.g. if you use labels

Then we use this environment for our math:

- `\begin{twocolequfloat}%` begin environment
- `\ensuremath{\hfill #1 \hfill}%` make sure formula set in mathmode, use `\hfill` to center it
- `\end{twocolequfloat}%` end environment

However, the formula will *always* be set to the bottom of the page. If your text ends after 20% of the page, the formula will be **far** away.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom. But I want it at the bottom of page not in the middle of it

Comment: So you wnat to write text (say two pages), somewhere write a formula, which is automatically moved to the bottom of the nearest apge?

Comment: Yes. I want that

Comment: There you go, _almost_ perfect. If you know how to check if the last page is completely filled and conditionally alter the environment...