# Add an equation at the bottom of a KOMA-script article in twocolumn mode

Tags: equations, positioning, koma-script, two-column

how can I place a large equation at the bottom of a page when using the document class `scrartcl` with the `twocolumn` option enabled.

I know about [this solution using multicols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28199/add-an-equation-at-the-bottom-of-a-two-column-article), but I'd rather stick with twocolumn mode and *not* use the `multicols` package because of problems with figure placements.

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: to clarify, I do *not* want to have the equation printed where it's defined, but rather on the bottom of the same page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: the accepted answer to this question [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430/579) describes an absolutely horrible hack to place a full-width insertion at the bottom of a two-column page.  (this is something that isn't supported natively by latex.)