# Add an equation at the bottom of a two-column conference paper

Tags: equations, positioning, two-column

The following related problem is what I am looking for but still cannot solve my question:

1. [Add an equation at the bottom of a two-column article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28199/add-an-equation-at-the-bottom-of-a-two-column-article)
2. [Add an equation at the bottom of a KOMA-script article in twocolumn mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155433/add-an-equation-at-the-bottom-of-a-koma-script-article-in-twocolumn-mode)

I am using a two-columns conference paper template, and I want to put the equation at the bottom of page.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}   
\usepackage{blindtext, graphicx}   
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage[tc]{titlepic}   
\usepackage{amssymb}   
\usepackage{amsfonts}   
\usepackage{lipsum}   
\usepackage{float}   
\usepackage{cuted}     
\usepackage{amsthm}   
\newtheoremstyle{case}{}{}{}{}{}{:}{ }{}

\begin{document}

\begin{strip}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
R = \begin{bmatrix} c\theta+n_1^2(1-c\theta) & n_1n_2(1-c\theta)    -n_3s\theta     & n_1n_3(1-c\theta)+n_2s\theta \\n_2n_1(1-c\theta)+n_3s\theta &     c\theta+n_2^2(1-c\theta) & n_2n_3(1-c\theta)-n_1s\theta \\n_3n_1    (1-c\theta)-n_2s\theta & n_3n_2(1-c\theta)+n_1s\theta & c\theta+n_3^2       (1-c\theta) \end{bmatrix}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{strip}

\end{document}
```

However, this equation shows up in the middle of that page. I want to put it at the bottom not the middle of page.

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Your code shows only the equation. How do you want we can test what's happening?

Comment: @Bernard I have no idea how to put my whole article here, which is too long. Could anyone please just show me how to do it? Or you could put arbitrary contents besides the equation.

Comment: The requirement is to use \begin{equation} \end{equation}.

Comment: Just put the preamble and some text with the `lipsum` package, for instance, so as to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to enclose your equation in `\begin{figure*} ... \end{figure*}`. with use of package `stfloats` it can be set on bottom of page:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext, graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[tc]{titlepic}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{case}{}{}{}{}{}{:}{ }{}

\usepackage{stfloats}% <-- added
\usepackage{showframe}% <-- only for show page layout, in real document had to be deleted
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{equation}
2+2=4
    \end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
    \begin{figure*}[b]
    \begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
R = \begin{bmatrix} 
c\theta+n_1^2(1-c\theta) & n_1n_2(1-c\theta)-n_3s\theta     
    &   n_1n_3(1-c\theta)+n_2s\theta    \\
n_2n_1(1-c\theta)+n_3s\theta 
    &   c\theta+n_2^2(1-c\theta) 
    & n_2n_3(1-c\theta)-n_1s\theta      \\
n_3n_1 (1-c\theta)-n_2s\theta 
    & n_3n_2(1-c\theta)+n_1s\theta & c\theta+n_3^2(1-c\theta)
    \end{bmatrix}.
\end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
    \end{figure*}
\lipsum[3-9]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just one question: what is \lipsum[2], \lipsum[3-9], what do they mean?

Comment: `\lipsum` generate dummy text, with option `[2]` is selected second paragraph in this text, with `[3-9]` paragraphs from 3 to 9.  With this paragraphs are simulated real text (which is not known to us).

Answer (score 2):

Zarko's answer was very helpful. I did as the answer described. My document had two column format.

The equation went to the bottom of the complete document. Instead, I wanted it to stay the bottom of the current page.

To solve this I went to ["stfloats" documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/sttools/stfloats.pdf).

> Dblfloats will appear on the same page where they are defined if they are
>   defined  on  left  column  and  enough free  place  is  available  on  the  current column/page.

This fixed my problem. Thank you.